# Como deixar DIVs auto-ajustáveis verticalmente?

Tags: html, css, front-end

Estou com problemas ao tentar deixar algumas `div`s auto-ajustáveis verticalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há o espaço necessário para a `div` ficar exatamente abaixo da que está acima dela, mas ela não sobe, fica um espaço vazio entre as duas. :'(

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37TBy/1/)

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "encaixar"?

Comment: @Sergio Espero ter esclarecido a dúvida.

Comment: Eu não sei ao certo explicar o por que (aguardo alguém fazer uma resposta com isso), mas retire o `float: left` e use apenas `display: inline-block` nos boxes. Também tire o tamanho fixo do contâiner, deixe a altura automática. Acho que esse é o objetivo: http://jsfiddle.net/37TBy/3/

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal , editei novamente colocando uma imagem explicativa que condiz com o objetivo.

Comment: Isso pode facilmente ser feito através do flexbox, recomendo dar uma pesquisada e estudada no assunto. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe um Javascript com o nome de [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) que pode ser utilizado para isso:

A configuração é muito simples, seguindo o seu próprio modelo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.container').isotope();
    });                   
</script>
```

*Código Html Completo*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $('.container').isotope();
            });                   
        </script>
        <style>
            *, html {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
           .container {
                width: 650px;
                height: 400px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            .box {
                width: 192px;
                margin: 2.5px;
                border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
                float: left;
                background-color: green;       
            }

            .box-1, .box-3, .box-5 {
                height: 120px;
            }

            .box-2, .box-4, .box-6 {
                height: 100px;
            }

            .box-5 {
                background-color: red !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box box-1"></div>
            <div class="box box-2"></div>
            <div class="box box-3"></div>
            <div class="box box-4"></div>
            <div class="box box-5"></div>
            <div class="box box-6"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DUmq8/)

*Possui várias configurações tudo* [**documentado no próprio site**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/index.html).

---

Além desse possui o [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) que pode ser chamado da mesma maneira que no primeiro exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
          $('.container').masonry();
    });                   
</script>
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MYWLm/)

*Masonry possui seu* [**GitHub**](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) *e a sua* [**documentação**](http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry-docs.zip).

Comment: muito bom os plugins, a pergunta não foi minha mas serviu pra mim tambem a resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente vejo esta estrutura em portais e nesse caso parece que trabalhar a estrutura dando ênfase às colunas de um grid é a melhor forma, pois em cada coluna teríamos os blocos dispostos um após o outro sem surgir os "buracos" no layout.

Fiz um rascunho rápido sobre a solução, observe:

http://codepen.io/marcosfreitas/pen/BKuvp

À propósito, as colunas não se comportaram muito bem com o "display: inline-block", por isso utilizei o "float: left" que ajusta melhor.

Comment: Parabéns, sua opção é bem melhor pois não utiliza framework nem plugin javascript

Comment: Obrigado. Atualmente podemos fazer melhor e organizar essa estrutura com flex-box do css3 de diversas maneiras. Veja este guia visual: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Comment: É isso aí!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo o **[Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)**

Instalando pelo Bower

```
bower install masonry --save
```

Ou **CDN**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

Usando:
**Jquery**

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

Usando Atributos no HTML

```
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }'>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Um exemplo de como é o resultado:
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/RPKgEN