# Como tirar blocos de uma grade?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer algo parecido com a timeline do facebook, duas colunas com várias postagens, o problema é, em algumas partes um buraco se abre, o motivo é que o bloco de baixo (à esquerda) está, no código, após o bloco acima (à direita).

[image: situação problema]

O que eu quero saber é: o que fazer para tirar esse buraco e juntar um bloco no outro ou ignorar essa posição no código e simplesmente juntar.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <article>
        <h3>Título</h3>
        <h6>Informações</h6>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h3>Título</h3>
        <h6>Informações</h6>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h3>Título</h3>
        <h6>Informações</h6>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper article {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
}
```

Comment: Patric dê uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23646/129

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode seguir a solução abaixo ou se preferir pode utilizar o [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Aqui está a solução em CSS

***CSS***

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper article {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

O resultado pode ser visto nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/6NJG4/4/)**

Comment: Tem um problema, quando chega em um certo ponto da página ele quebra a postagem no meio e continua na segunda coluna.

Comment: @Patrick poderia publicar no jsfiddle o seu código para eu analisar?

Comment: É o mesmo da pergunta, a única diferença é que não tem o texto.

Comment: Solução http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/6NJG4/3/ adicione no article o seguinte `display: inline-block; width: 100%;`

Comment: Vou usar o Masonry, parece mais viável.